# Нужны ли кавычки в этих предложениях?

Tags: кавычки

Понятие "этническая культура" включает в себя определенный набор характерных черт,...
Ключевое место в определении понятия "этноса" отводится культурной памяти народа.
Понятие "культурная память" рассматривается с точки зрения определения, данного М. А. Родионовым в монографии...
Под термином "модернизация" понимается процесс активного, последовательного внедрения инноваций...

Нужны ли кавычки в этих предложениях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки нужны во всех примерах, кроме этого: "*в определении понятия этноса*" (термин понятия в *родительном* падеже).

> Розенталь: Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация. РАЗДЕЛ 17
> Употребление кавычек § 58.1: *Кавычками выделяются: 7) слова,
> разъясняющие термины, выражения... Раскрыть понятие «дуализм»*
>
> https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827548.html
>
> *Когда термин понятия фигурирует в **именительном** падеже, он заключается
> в кавычки. Если же термин понятия фигурирует в **родительном** падеже, то
> он в кавычки **не** заключaeтся.*  (С.К. Абачиев, Формальная логика с
> элементами теории познания, 2012, с. 85)

Comment: Понятие «этноса» и его признаки. https://studwood.ru/629060/sotsiologiya/ponyatie_etnosa_priznaki  Это ошибочное написание или оно допускается в каких-то случаях?

Comment: Думаю, что здесь ошибка и что допустимо такое в случаях скептического или иронического отношения к определяемому (по аналогии со случаем "так называемого"). Не нашёл в учебниках, поэтому сослался на книжку, в которой автор сделал специальное отступление в область правописания (по его же словам).